# Angular-Formly - Access Model names for calculated fields with key names containing dot(.)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I have a config json with 3 fields, the 3rd field being a calculated field from data in the previous 2 fields.
Now the catch here is I have dot(.) in their key names. e.g. "something.someone"
When I try rendering the form I get an error showing undefined.
My config_json :

```
{
"fieldGroupClassName": "row",
"fieldGroup": [
{
            "className": "col-2",
            "key": "remarks_backflow.bed",
            "type": "input",
            "templateOptions": {
              "type": "number",
              "label": "Bed",
              "placeholder": "",
              "required": true
            }
          },
{
            "className": "col-2",
            "key": "remarks_backflow.gas",
            "type": "input",
            "templateOptions": {
              "type": "number",
              "label": "Gas",
              "placeholder": "",
              "required": true
            }
          },
{
            "className": "col-2",
            "key": "remarks_backflow.diff",
            "type": "input",
            "templateOptions": {
              "type": "number",
              "label": "Difference",
              "placeholder": "",
              "required": true
            },
            "expressionProperties": {
              "model['remarks_backflow.diff']":"model['remarks_backflow.bed'] - model['remarks_backflow.gas']"
            }
          },
]
}
```

The error is :
FormBuilderComponent.html:24 ERROR TypeError: [Formly Error] [Expression "model['pushin_temperature.kiln_id']"] Cannot set property 'kiln_id']' of undefined
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above question has been clarified and solved in a github thread of ngx-formly and
the link for the same :
[ngx-formly github](https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/issues/2916)